# ¿Como mostrar datos de un servicio en un mat table usando reactive forms?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

Tengo la siguiente tabla donde el objetivo es que muestre los datos traidos de un servicio y que permita editar los campos, por eso usa componentes como mat input y mat select, para que el usuario pueda modificar lo que se muestra del servicio.

asi tengo mi html pero al cargar la pantalla no muestra los datos del servicio, al desplegar los mat select, si muestra la informacion, pero no muestra por default el valor que trae de la BD

```
       <mat-accordion class="example-headers-align" multi>
            <mat-expansion-panel>
                <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <mat-panel-title class="text">
                       Productos
                    </mat-panel-title>
                </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                <div class="scrollme">
                    <form [formGroup]="productosForm">
                        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

                            <ng-container matColumnDef="cveProducto">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> PRODUCTO </th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.cveProducto}} </td>
                            </ng-container>

                            <ng-container matColumnDef="idProd">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> TIPO </th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                    <mat-form-field>
                                        <mat-select [(value)]="element.idProd" class="select-css"
                                            formControlName="idProd">
                                            <mat-option *ngFor="let tipo of tipoModelo" [value]="tipo.idProd">
                                                {{tipo.descTipo}}
                                            </mat-option>
                                        </mat-select>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </td>
                            </ng-container>
                            
                            <ng-container matColumnDef="idGrupo">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> GRUPO </th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                    <mat-form-field>
                                        <mat-select [(value)]="element.idGrupo" class="select-css"
                                            formControlName="idGrupo">
                                            <mat-option *ngFor="let grupo of gpoModelo" [value]="grupo.idGrupo">
                                                {{grupo.descGpo}}
                                            </mat-option>
                                        </mat-select>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </td>
                            </ng-container>

                            <ng-container matColumnDef="descripcionProducto">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> DESCRIPCIÓN </th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                        <input matInput [value]="element.descripcionProducto" formControlName="descripcionProducto">
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </td>
                            </ng-container>

                            <ng-container matColumnDef="claveUb">
                                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> CLAVE </th>
                                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                                    <mat-form-field>
                                        <mat-select formControlName="claveUb">
                                            <mat-option *ngFor="let ubix of cveUbix" [value]="ubix.valor">
                                                {{ubix.label}}
                                            </mat-option>
                                        </mat-select>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </td>
                            </ng-container>
                            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns">
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </mat-expansion-panel>
        </mat-accordion>
```

component.ts

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['cveProducto', 'idProd', 'idGrupo','descripcionProducto', 'claveUb'];
     productoModelo: Producto[] = [];
     tipoModelo: TipoProducto[] = [];
     gpoModelo: GpoProducto[] = [];
  
        
    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.obtenerProductos();
    this.obtenerGpos();
    this.obtenerTipos();

    this.productosForm = new FormGroup({
      idProd: new FormControl(''),
      idGrupo: new FormControl(''),
      descripcionProducto: new FormControl(''),
      claveUb: new FormControl(''),
    })
  }

  cveUbix = [
    { label: 'Si', valor: 1 },
    { label: 'No', valor: 0 },
  ];


  dataSource: any;
  obtenerProductos() {
    this.productService.obtenerProducto().subscribe(response => {
      if (response.data.length == 0) {
        Swal.fire({
          icon: 'error',
          text: 'Sin datos para mostrar'
        })
      } else {
        this.productoModelo = response.data;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.productoModelo);
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      }

    });
  }

  dataSourceTipoProd: any;
  obtenerTipos() {
    this.productService.obtenerTiposProd().subscribe(response => {
      if (response.data.length == 0) {
        Swal.fire({
          icon: 'error',
          text: 'Sin datos para mostrar'
        })
      } else {
        this.tipoModelo = response.data;
        this.dataSourceTipoProd = new MatTableDataSource(this.tipoModelo);
        this.dataSourceTipoProd.paginatorCatalogos = this.paginatorCatalogos;
      }

    });
  }

  dataSourceGpoProd: any;
  obtenerGpos() {
    this.productService.obtenerGpoProd().subscribe(response => {
      if (response.data.length == 0) {
        Swal.fire({
          icon: 'error',
          text: 'Sin datos para mostrar'
        })
      } else {
        this.gpoModelo = response.data;
        this.dataSourceGpoProd = new MatTableDataSource(this.gpoModelo);
        this.dataSourceGpoProd.paginatorCatalogos = this.paginatorCatalogos;
      }

    });
  }
```

que tengo que cambiar o que me esta faltando para que al cargar la pagina, la tabla me muestre los dats del servcio